# MySQL - phpMyadmin - Error #1064

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE TABLE 'serverlist' (
'ID' int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
'Name' text NOT NULL,
'Number' text NOT NULL,
'BuyIn' DOUBLE NOT NULL default'0',
'BuyIn2' DOUBLE NOT NULL default'0',
'Limit' int(5) NOT NULL default'0',
'AvgPot' DOUBLE NOT NULL default'0',
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

^This results in the following error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''serverlist' ( 'ID' int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment, 'Name' text NOT NULL, 'Nu' at line 1`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

change simple quotes by back quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE `serverlist` (
`ID` int(4) NOT NULL auto_in
...
```

Comment: is there a difference between this and not having any quotes at all?

Comment: with quotes you can use spaces in table and field names also reserved words as identifiers.